# With jQuery Impromptu, how to close a dialog and pop up another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, impromptu

I've got an ajax call happening that has a $prompt dialog open.  I want to close that dialog and put up another one.  How can I do that?

```
            if (dataNew.Message && dataNew.Message.length > 0) {
                $.prompt.close();
                $.prompt("Problem", dataNew.Message);
            }
```

The above does not work. The original dialog stays open.

Comment: More an observation as I was unable to recreate your issue. Are you not passing the params incorrectly? - ie {message: dataNew.Message}. It makes me wonder how you are initializing the other. From here- http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Comment: After more thinking about it, I don't really want to close the prompt, changing state makes more sense.  Just wrapping my head around that. -thanks